# Keeping mmenu visible after closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I'm wondering if it is possible to control where mmenu closes to. For example when mmenu is closed I want to see a thin vertical strip on the left of the screen, but when opened it will open up to its standard width.

Ideally, when closed the thin vertical strip will show a list of icons and then when expanded there will also be text with the icons.

Can I do this with mmenu?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply but maybe useful to some..

There is now an extension that does this. http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/extensions/iconbar.html